# /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.2.8/priv/bin/memsup: Erlang has closed.

Tags: erlang

This my MakeFile

```
run:    
    ERL_LIBS=apps:deps 
    erl +K true +A 2 +a 16 +e 10 +d -name my_server@127.0.0.1 -pa ebin -pa apps/*/ebin -pa deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl -s my_server -sasl errlog_type error
```

The error when run `make run`

```
ERL_LIBS=apps:deps 
erl +K true +A 2 +a 16 +e 10 +d -name my_server@127.0.0.1 -pa ebin -pa apps/*/ebin -pa deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl -s my_server -sasl errlog_type error
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:2] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
(my_server@127.0.0.1)1> Erlang has closed
/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.2.8/priv/bin/memsup: Erlang has closed. 
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

How to get the reason why the application can not be started  ?

Comment: We need more information.. can you post the contents of your sasl log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Erlang has closed" error is shown when mem_sup is shutdown, it is totally normal behaviour when a system is stopping.

Most probably there is something going wrong in my_server.